# Dividing the result of 2 subqueries by each other

Tags: mysql, group-by

Most questions I have seen seem to be carrying out operations on subqueries where the output is of 1 single value.

I just carried out 2 queries. The first one gives me the count of footballers for each club

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count
FROM player_info i
GROUP BY i.club
ORDER BY i.club;
```

Output

```
club        count
Arsenal       60
Bournemouth   52
```

and the second one gives me the count of English footballers from each club.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count
FROM player_info i
WHERE i.region = 1 
GROUP BY i.club
ORDER BY i.club;
```

Output

```
club        count
Arsenal       5
Bournemouth   7
```

How can I divide them to get a percentage? In other words,

Output

```
club        count
Arsenal       5/60
Bournemouth   7/52
```

So far, I have tried using JOINS, and copy-pasting the above codes into a large SELECT(), but the error is **"Subquery returns more than 1 row."**

```
SELECT i.club, COUNT(*), x.count / y.count(SELECT COUNT(*) as count
FROM player_info i
WHERE i.region = 1 
GROUP BY i.club
ORDER BY i.club) AS x (SELECT COUNT(*) as count
FROM player_info i
GROUP BY i.club
ORDER BY i.club) AS y
FROM player_info i
WHERE i.region = 1 
GROUP BY i.club
ORDER BY i.club;
```

I'm having some syntax error from the starting 'SELECT'.

Comment: see edit for example. Because I added in the line ORDER BY club, hence the values will correspond will each other for the 2 outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT i.club, AVG(i.region = 1) AS percentage
FROM player_info i
GROUP BY i.club
ORDER BY i.club;
```

Comment: Thanks, the solution is much simpler than I imagined! However, I would still like to learn from what I did wrong. Could you please point out what I did wrong from the question?

Comment: Your query, as  you posted it,is not valid syntactically. One of the errors is that this: `SELECT i.club, COUNT(*), x.count / y.count` should be followed by a FROM clause and after the FROM clause there should be the 1st subquery cross joind with the 2nd subquery. But all this is unnecessary.

Comment: I would like to take the chance to ask another small related question, since I don't think it warrants me creating another post. If I do a query `COUNT(*)` to find the number of players in each club, why is it that `COUNT(i.region=1)` to find all the count of English players in each club doesn't work? I had to use a `SUM(CASE WHEN i.region=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` instead.

Comment: `i.region=1` returns 1 (true) or 0 (false), so count(i.region=1) would count 1s and 0s together because count() does not count only the null values.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are saying that `COUNT` counts the number of rows, regardless of whether they are 1 or 0, is that correct? In that case, another question I have is, do you have a more succinct way of querying what I want instead of the `SUM(CASE...)` query I wrote above? I feel like it can be improved but not sure how.

Comment: Your understanding about COUNT() is correct. For SUM() it can be simplified to: `SUM(i.region=1)` because it will actually sum only the 1s.

Comment: By 1s I mean when the expression `i.region=1` is TRUE.